# Why the output is not shown at compile time?

Tags: java

I know that static blocks are executed at class loading time. I want to ask -are they statically loaded or dynamically loaded? Because I came to know that there are two types of class loading-static and dynamic. If they are statically loaded then why their output is shown at run-time not at compile-time?

Comment: which jvm should give you the output at compile time?

Comment: i am confused -that classes are loaded at compile time and static blocks are executed at class loading time means at compile time..it should mean that the output is ready at compile time....am i right?so why does the output produced at run time..

Comment: Compiling simply creates a binary file representation of your .java file and creates a represeneting .class file in exchange. There is nothing done with loading of variables or something like that at compile time. If you want further information you could check [JLS 13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html)

Answer (score 1):

> I know that static blocks are executed at class loading time.

That's not entirely accurate.  They are executed when the class is *initialized*.  That happens sometime between the time that the class is loaded and the class is "used".

> -are they (static blocks) statically loaded or dynamically loaded?

Static blocks are loaded at the same time as the class that they are part of.  Classes can be statically loaded or dynamically loaded.

However, in the Java context, "static loading" still happens at runtime.

The distinction between static and dynamic loading in Java is between classes that are loaded because they are named by a Java identifier in the source code, and classes that are loaded by calling `Class.forName(name)`, and equivalent.

> If they are statically loaded then why their output is shown at run-time not at compile-time?

In the Java context, *all* loading occurs at runtime.  So all output from static blocks will be shown at runtime.